# Overriding members and lazy val

Tags: scala, constructor, lazy-evaluation

I found [this explanation](https://github.com/paulp/scala-faq/wiki/Initialization-Order) on how to propagate overriden member values to superclass constructors by using *lazy val*. Unfortunately, the article does not explain why this works.

I understand than non-lazy values cannot be assigned twice and that therefore, no value is available in a super constructor since the value assignment in the super class constructor must be skiped in order to not lock the variable to another value. However, how can the *println* statement - which is executed in the super constructor, i.e. before the new lazy value is asigned - already know about this new value? Am I confusing something about the execution order? Or is *println* somehow only evaluating its argument after the object is constructed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You just should note that all fields and lazy fields are getter methods.

`val` getter returns value of `private[this]` field. `private[this]` field assignment is located in primary constructor:

```
class Test {
  val field = 1
}
```

means something like this:

```
class Test {
  private[this] val _field: Int = _
  def field = _field

  {  // constructor
    _field = 1
  }
}
```

So before constructor `field` returns default value.

`lazy val` evaluates block of code using double check lock and than returns result:

```
class Test {
  lazy val field = 1
}
```

means something like this:

```
class Test {
  private[this] val _field: Int = _
  @volatile private[this] val _flag: Boolean = _

  def field = {
    if (! _flag) {
      synchronized {
        if (! _flag) {
          _field = 1 // code block
          _flag = true
        }
      }
    }

    _field
  }
}
```

So `lazy val` has nothing with constructor, you'll get same result before and after constructor.

You could check this using `scalac -Xprint:mixin test.scala`.

Comment: This makes it somehow clearer. However, I still wonder how the getter can access the field's value, before it is set to the actual value in the subconstructor. In my understanding, the println code line should be executed before the JVM even reaches the statement where the new value is set. How is this possible? Does println not need to resolve the getter and therefore access the underlying value when executed?

Comment: @raphw which `println` do you mean?

Comment: @raphw: In `Use lazy vals.` example all `println` calls 2 methods: `x1` and `x2`. `x1` is defined in `B` and has nothing with constructor. You could just define it as `def`, not `val` and `lazy val`. `x2` is defined in `A` and than overridden in `C`. It also has nothing with constructor. Method not overridden in constructor, it's just overridden. Try to replace all `val` and `lazy val` in this example with `def` - result would be the same.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. I overlooked how the keyword changed the entire implementation from constructor to method initialization.

Comment: The more I think about this, the less I like it. I could think of hundret szenarios where some `lazy val = func()` would create a deadlock because of the `this` monitor synchronization. And then, I discovered that the Scala developers consider this a user bug: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5808?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel - Thanks though!